# Corner Bathtub with Faucet Holes?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I need to replace a corner acrylic bathtub from 2005.  My plumber doesn't know anything about what we have installed here; I bougth this house and don't know the model number of any the bath parts.

It's a Kohler tub, and Kohler is going to try to identify what part number it is (in 5 business days...).

Currently with Kohler I don't see any corner tubs with the faucet holes drilled out like this.  No one at Kohler knows anything what this is.

Do you actually just drill out the acrylic tubs like these for the faucet and mixer?

The frame that the tub is in has front panels, that can be pulled apart to access the mixing valves.

Any one with some experience who knows what this tub?

[image]

Comment: isn't it possible the faucet fittings were drilled/installed when the tub was installed?  if you measure the installed size, ill bet you can fit a replacement into the same "corner box".  also, they have several models with "therapy jets" as long as your upgrading...

Comment: @mark f -- I'm wondering the same thing.  Kohler rep (who seemed clueless) said it would be pre-drilled, but all I'm seeing is non-predrilled.  It's acrylic so seems like you could drill through.  My plumber is kind of clueless on this too.  It's a builder house, so this was done the cheapest way possible for certain!

Comment: here is the 60x60 version from lowes,  there are also 54x54 and larger version too. https://www.lowes.com/pd/KOHLER-Tercet-60-in-W-x-60-in-L-White-Acrylic-Corner-Front-Center-Drain-Alcove-Bathtub/999967249

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put those in and depending on the model they do not have the holes. I have installed them reversed  to what you have (almost) you could reach the 3 handled for the faucet mounted on the wall, I am sure the same tub. I also have installed other tubs with the taps in the wall and 1 like yours where I had to use a hole saw to drill the 3 holes not hard but I recommend sharp or new hole saws and water on the cut like a spray bottle to keep it cool the faucet pieces are larger than the holes but 800$ tub is easy to mess up trying to use a dull 25$ hole saw.

Comment: Thanks, sir!  Kohler rep doesn't have a clue....